# video resource won't play in wpf mediaelement

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a problem trying to play a video inside my wpf application.

```
 <MediaElement LoadedBehavior="Manual" x:Name="myMediaElement" Stretch="UniformToFill" >
        <MediaElement.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MediaElement.Loaded">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <MediaTimeline Name="asdasdasd" 
                                           Source="pack://application:,,/Media/login-loop.wmv"   
                                           Storyboard.TargetName="myMediaElement" 
                                           RepeatBehavior="Forever"  />

                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </MediaElement.Triggers>
    </MediaElement>
```

When I try to play the video stream from an embedded resource it fails to play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks, but i solved my problem.
i just Added my video as a resource element. next, by code I get the resource Stream, then I write it to temp folder, get the path and put in mediaElement

Answer (score 0):

You cannot embed a video into an assembly as a resource and play it from a MediaElement.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/150cb4e7-9107-4d07-8c81-6c2ef9734529/how-to-play-a-wmv-file-as-a-embed-resource-in-resourceresx-with-mediaelement-not-content?forum=wpf

The closest you might be able to do is to either add the file as `content` and play it from the file system, or have a preload task that copies the file out of the resource and onto the file system before you play.